# Spring boot archetypes not available after 1.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot

I have no problem on generating a project like this with maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-sample-simple-archetype \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.springframework.boot \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2.RELEASE \
-Dversion=0.1-SNAPSHOT \
-DgroupId=org.demo \
-DartifactId=demo \
-DpackageName=demo;
```

But when I change to a more recent version such as 1.4.1.RELEASE I get an error saying the desired archetype does not exist.

Why is there not any spring boot archetypes available for versions after 1.0.2.RELEASE? Any chances the spring-boot team will include them at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's answered here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6063
Basically, they won't invest time into Maven archetypes, instead they provide the Spring Initializr at [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) which has the same or even more functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the archtypes to Eclipse ID. You have to download them of this site: https://repo.spring.io/release/archetype-catalog.xml

Comment: Well, those are actually the ones from 1.0.2. As indicated in my question they are not available any more from that version on. Much better to use start.spring.io as indicated by dunni. Also, you can take advantage of curl to do everything in one command with something like `curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=simple | tar -xzvf -`